# Establishing a relationship between ViewModels in different windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

My program is structured in the following way:

---

**MainWindow:**

Window->ViewModel

UserControl1(Bound to `contentPresenter`)->ViewModel->Model

^`TreeView`(In UC1)->***ViewModel***->Model

**Child Window:**

Window->ViewModel

UserControl2(Bound to `contentPresenter`)->***ViewModel***->Model

---

*The child window is created and opened from the UC1->ViewModel.

I need to create a relationship between the bold italicized ViewModels. Specifically this is the ViewModel in the User Control of the child window, and the ViewModel of the `TreeView` in the mainWindow's User Control.

This is necessary because I would like to add nodes to the `TreeView` from the child window. The problem is that, although I setup a property in UC2->VM for `TreeView`(UC1)->VM, I receive a `NullReferenceException` because UC2->VM is not able to set the property equal to anything but a new TV->VM.

**Code:**

UserControl2->ViewModel

```
public ViewModel _TreeVM;
private Command _newNode;

public UserControl2_VM()
{
    _newNode = new Command(NewNode_Operations);
}

public ViewModel TreeVM
{
    get { return _TreeVM; }
    set
    {
        _TreeVM = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => TreeVM);
    }
}

//Command -- Adds new node
public Command NewNode { get { return _newNode; } }
private void NewNode_Operations()
{
    TreeVM.addNewNode(); //**NullReferenceException
}
```

`DataTemplate` in Child Window:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type project:UserControl2_VM}">
            <UC:ChildWindowUC/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

*How can I make it so that I can access the `TreeView`'s viewModel from the ViewModel in the child window's User Control?*

Comment: Pass in the Parent to the child ViewModel?

Comment: If you're saying pass to the ViewModel of the Child Window(not UserControl2->VM), I'm confused on how to do that, because the CW's ViewModel is created using a `DataTemplate` (Rather than using `DataContext`).

Comment: Then whatever the ItemsSource of that DataTemplate (TreeView), you should pass in the parent there when it is being created. And I doubt that the DataTemplate is creating the ViewModel.

Comment: I put the `DataTemplate` in the question for you. It does not have an `ItemsSource` that I am aware of. I also think that it is creating the ViewModel, because I don't create it in c# anywhere.

Comment: That's just the View though, where is the ViewModel for that and how is it populated? What is DataTemplate? Datatemplate of what?

Comment: Shoot, I think I slipped up earlier. In code-behind for my child Window I have `DataContext = childWindowViewModel();` (Maybe I can pass the ViewModel there?). Does that answer your question? And `DataTemplate` is for the user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the ParentViewModel to the ChildViewModel so you can have reference to it.

```
DataContext = childWindowViewModel(ParentViewModel);
```

Comment: So am I passing UC1->ViewModel, or `TreeView`->ViewModel?

Comment: Also, my child window can't see any of the Parent items.

Comment: Pass the ViewModel of UC1 to the ChildWindowViewModel It can't see the parent items? Why not? That doesn't make sense.